# xdotool does not type for me

Tags: xdotool

xdotool no longer types anything. It worked well a few days ago.

for example this command has no outputs (and no errors):

```
xdotool type 'Hello world!'
```

What is the problem?

I uninstalled and reinstalled it. But nothing was solved.

```
xdotool --version
xdotool version 3.20130506.1
```

Comment: What version of xdotool do you have? What terminal emulator are you using? What desktop environment?

Comment: the last available for 13.10 in repo. Any terminal, KDE.

Comment: Please run `xdotool --version` and [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: edited‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: screenshot would be better.

Comment: screen shot for a completely text-based (console) app?!

Comment: xdotool is very cool, but you may want to consider trying autokey-qt. It does a lot of what xdotool does, but lets you configure everything in a gui. It's a full keyboard macro system with phrases and scripting in Python. Find info at `https://code.google.com/p/autokey/w/list`.  It installs best from its ppa - `ppa:cdekter/ppa`.

Comment: @Joe. So do you have an answer for http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131253/an-alternative-to-xdotool-type?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - Thanks! I posted an answer there.